# Apple GLPaint with varying width

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, opengl-es, paint

Can anybody suggest how I could get GLPaint example to work with varying brush size? Let's just say I want to draw with randomly varying brush size (using some random number generator for the brush size) as I go along. There are no other rules - just keep drawing with a sensibly varying brush size.

Answer (score 0):

Look for `#define kBrushScale` constant in glpaint example. you need to replace the constant with random ivar. Also the brushscale is based on the particle.png size. i.e., increasing `kBrushScale` reduces the storkewidth

good luck.

**Update:**

`kBrushScale` was used to define the `glPointSize` at initWithCoder only once. You need to replace the constant with ivar and update the `glPointSize` before drawing new line segment.

eg., I have added the following line of code in my `renderLineFromPoint:toPoint:`

```
glPointSize(arc4random()%kBrushScale); //random brush/point size
```

Comment: If I change the `kBrushScale` the width of the entire trail changes. I do not want that. I want the trail to have different widths at different points. The width should change based on the amount of pinch.

Comment: Yes, thats why it is declared as constant. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: Alright, so I added the following code in renderLineFromPoint:toPoint:     
u_int32_t number = arc4random()%kBrushScale;
NSLog(@"%d", number);
glPointSize(number); 
and I see a lot of 0's and 1's printed out in the log. And in the actual display, I don't see the "SHAKE ME" drawing coming up either...